# Trying to backup system state on server 2003 sp2, getting "Faulting application vssvc.exe - system state backup failed" in applciation log

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, vss

Trying to backup system state on Windows Server 2003 (SP2), getting "Faulting application vssvc.exe - system state backup failed" in application log.

```
Volume shadow copy creation: Attempt 1.
"MSDEWriter" has reported an error 0x800423f2. This is part of System State. The volume shadow copy operation can be retried.
"Event Log Writer" has reported an error 0x800423f2. This is part of System State. The volume shadow copy operation can be retried.
"Registry Writer" has reported an error 0x800423f2. This is part of System State. The volume shadow copy operation can be retried.
"COM+ REGDB Writer" has reported an error 0x800423f2. This is part of System State. The volume shadow copy operation can be retried.
"Removable Storage Manager" has reported an error 0x0. This is part of System State. The backup cannot continue.

Error returned while creating the volume shadow copy:800423f2
Aborting Backup.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting the server and then run "vssadmin list writers" from a command prompt to check the status of the VSS writers on the server.

Comment: already tried that, did not fix

Comment: What's the status of the writers?

Comment: after reboot, no errors, once I backup, errors on WMI and System writers

Comment: Found these. Don't know if they're exactly applicable: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915331. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;833167.